# How to split multi line sentences without delimiters('.','?','!')?

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

> I have extracted text from pdf and trying to split it into sentences.
> text sample in repr form -
>
> ```
> "This is multiline text without any delimiter need to \n be considered as one sentence \n Whereas this sentence is one liner \n Slash n or first char capital is not option as sentences of \n Dhiraj's sample can contain first letter capital even its not a new sentence"
> ```
>
> result should be like -
>
> ```
> ["This is multiline text without any delimiter need to be considered as one sentence","Whereas this sentence is one liner","Slash n or first char capital is not option as sentences of Dhiraj's sample can contain first letter capital even its not a new sentence"]
> ```
>
> my temporary solution is to get the max length of sentence and consider it as multi line sentence and remove /n there. but it is not reliable.

Comment: I'm affraid your question has no solution.

Comment: @Synthase it is possible if i am able to detect an incomplete sentence.

Comment: Well so define what is an incomplete sentence or what is a complete sentence. If capital letters and \n are not option there is no way. Plus you have no period. No way.

Comment: training a binary classification model that can classify sentence as complete/incomplete is possible but its kind of overkill.

Comment: Yes it is. Good luck. And it will never be 100%. I would recommend to review the process leading to that input, and find a way to leave a delimiter in it.

Comment: This seems to be a typical "bad input" leading to wicked algorithm and unreliable output. But if you insist in going this way, use google translate API to translate the capitalised words, if the result is the same it probably means that it is a proper name and does not indicate the start of a new sentence, and the result will probably be correct.... or probably not.

Comment: @Raf that's a pretty smart way to detect names tbh. Never thought about it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution but it requires some handwork,

- Create a list that includes proper names, find all the proper names in the text
  with that list, and convert them to lowercase letters with a search method.
- Then write your main code block, separating the text into sentences using the first capital letters.
- At the end re-capitalize the names in the text using the name list.

Comment: Working on similar solution.thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Yeah but same what if you get a city name.. an abbrev or anything.

Comment: can check for proper noun using nltk